# Textblock lostfocus event doesnt work as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a popup with listbox in it and this listbox is associated with a textbox.

Now while handling the lostfocus event for textbox, it works correctly when i try to click on other controls but the lostfocus doesnt get called when I try to click on window.Can somebody help me with this.

```
<TextBox x:name="txtbox1"/> 
    <Popup StaysOpen="False"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtbox1}" 
           Placement="Bottom">
    <ListBox x:Name="CompanyListBox">         
</Popup>
```

In constructor, I have txtbox1.LostFocus+="txtbox1_OnLostFocus"

```
private void txtbox1_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox1.Text))
  {
    txtbox1.Text = DefaultFeature;
    Popup.IsOpen = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the event handler for text box?

Comment: What do you mean with *"I try to click on window"*? Naturally, there are parts of a window that don't make a control lose its focus just by clicking on them... (for example, clicking on a window caption bar or opening a menu does *not* make a textbox or such lose the focus)

Comment: Exactly so i need to handle the event when the user tries to click on the caption bar or certain parts of window where the control doesnt loses its focus. The problem here is when I try to drag the window, I need the popup listbox to get closed.

Comment: Cannot use combobox here as I have configured the textbox to be Autocomplete one.

Comment: Can I may be handle the Mousedown event on the window and close the popup there?

Comment: If you just want an autocomplete combobox, have you tried using a combobox and setting its `IsTextSearchEnabled` property to `true`? ([Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.textsearch.aspx) for some examples of how TextSearch can be utilized)

Comment: So I tried handling the MouseDown for the window and it works fine i.e. the Mousedown gets triggered if I click on other parts of window, except for the caption\title bar. Is there any specific for handling click events for title bar? I will keep in mind combobox option from the next time.